# Force an AND search between 2 fields in CCK?

Tags: k2, joomla-3.4, zoo-cck

I'm trying to find a way to use Zoo or K2 (or another CCK) to create a set of customer records. The customer would be able to enter BOTH their last name and an ID code into two fields in a search module. Only a match to BOTH fields would return a result (their record).

It's hard to tell if Zoolanders ZooFilter or the various K2 filters out there can be forced to only display two fields and force a AND relationship between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, Zoolanders ZooFilter (a paid module) works perfectly for this sort of thing along size Yootheme Zoo.

[Zoolanders ZooFilter](https://www.zoolanders.com/extensions/zoofilter)

[Yootheme Zoo](http://yootheme.com/zoo)